# RSA (RFC 4716) Public key in RSAParameter dotNet c#

Tags: c#, .net, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I try to decrypt message with `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and `RSAParameters` to store my key values (Modulus, Exponent, ...). But i don't know how to import a `RFC 4716` key. (I tried lot of thing, convert into PEM format, extract Modulus and Exponent ... but no once work)

*pub key file* :

`ssh-rsa AAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC+YshbLzdlXXBjyj2DpbQYgBzw+CfBOM82pOxCpEH0LP275gvswfCAwv/QXETrDqhspJBDT4jR4EYtpvH/sC8KLs17q6m9q/5va2g5SP6QQlOxyuSvlTWPa10/sYpyE2zkkJ09Nrkaacoh5iEQjXEJWbPWPvMAO5FkFjGkfS+nZ7nCdI9LTzuy33/5Wi7EDquLzV+094/Dxt0z9HP+Y73gh/2ENA0QKyhj7Idmg2IlyPFKm/6QAMGiUdI/cJoGXylo88GR9kjCH41ZpovlIPczcvrM5uB/m8cQfyUivAhaN4377zpJSTzxMTJmfWhAol1WdJs+PSdzzvOlTK26PnYj test`

Comment: Seems like there is none. Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457710/converting-an-rsa-public-key-into-a-rfc-4716-public-key-with-bouncy-castle you "just" have to reverse the steps suggested by Pavel Korsukov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solution i found is to use the XML key format from dotNet and use library to use it on Javascript

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18026423/6806288